# Can the select option value attribute be a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, json, mongodb

To summarize, I've got a collection in a mongodb database that stores "username" and "email" and I would like to make a page on a localhost web server that displays the username and email of a specific user based on a selection from a drop down menu. I've made the drop down menu but I can't get an appropriate "value" so that I can pull the correct username/email from my collection.

```
    <select id="user" onchange="setUser()">
        <option selected disabled>Choose a user</option>
        <%
        var list = '';
        for (i = 0; i < userlist.length; i++) {
        list += '<option value=i>' + userlist[i].username + '</option>';
        }
        %>
        <%- list %>
    </select>
```

Everything works the way I expect but I just get the character 'i' as the value instead of an int value. All of this is new to me within the last few days - I've never done any sort of web development before so if you could be as informational as possible in your responses I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happening because you are using a string literal instead of a variable in the value.
You should change this line

```
list += '<option value=i>' + userlist[i].username + '</option>';
```

to

```
list += '<option value="' +i+'">'+ userlist[i].username + '</option>';
```

Orrrrr,

Since the above code looks very messy, you can simply use template literals to make your code look cleaner:

```
list += `<option value="${i}">${userlist[i].username} </option>`;
```

Notice that here I have used caret(`) instead of quote '.
In a template literal , everything that is enclosed in a `${}` is a variable value and rest are string literals.

To learn more about Template Literals you can check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Wow - that was an embarrassing mistake! I'm still getting used to switching between just writing html and writing little scripts that make html and that one got past me. Thank you!

Comment: No problem.It happens to the best of us